# Best practices on assumptions of Synchronicity/Asynchronicity

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two questions regarding the same topic dependend on the angle of view.

Let's assume there's a function that accepts a callback that receives the return value of the executed function:

```
function myFunction( callback ) {
    //do something
    callback( something );
}
```

Now someone invokes this function:

```
myFunction( function( something ) {
    console.log( 'a' );
} );

console.log( 'b' );
```

My point is:
Is it always save for the user (the one that invokes the function) to make an assumption about the order of the events 'a' and 'b'? Resulting: Is it considered bad coding style to rely on the exact behaviour? (Not talking about the runnig time but about synchronicity or asynchronicity!) Someone might think that `myFunction` is asynchronous thus 'b' has to happen *always* before 'a'.

The other way around:
As the someone who designs a certain function, is it considered bad coding style to have not a predictable order? Maybe it is necessary to wait for a certain event to happen, resulting in an asynchronous answer, or maybe this exact action has not to be awaited thus asynchronicity is not required. 
Would it be the best in this case to add a process.nextTick(...) to always have the same behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If a developer wants to be safe, they should understand how `myFunction` behaves before using it.

Comment: that's a very diplomatic answer :)  what in the case of the designer of that function?

Comment: ...responding to your comment below, it wouldn't be wise to create a function where the user can not predict its behavior. If you can optimize a particular situation by making it behave synchronously, you should probably still document it as an asynchronous function that requires a callback. When it ends up being synchronous, you can still fire the callback when ready.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you should code so that it doesn't matter. However, there are cases in which emitting events must be delayed, for example, if something emits an event on itself in the constructor - there's no way you can already listen for it at that time.

Comment: yes, i see your point, in the case of the event in the constructor the programmer has to make sure it gets delayed. but what's the case when someone is calling a function and *this time* it is not neccessary (no IO, FS access...) to make it asynchrounos whereas in another case it *is* neccessary?

Comment: @zaphod1984: Assume that it might call back immediately unless the modules docs or its code say otherwise. Normally, it doesn't make your code more complex, so why not?

Comment: getting back to your example i made a gist: https://gist.github.com/1834492 i did not made this up, i came exactly across this problem what led me to this question. if `someAsynchrounosFunction` would not behave asynchrounos as expected, that code what not work.